# Nestjs - Routes defined within controllers are overriding each other

Tags: nestjs

I have a controller

```
//imports etc
...

@Get('me')
async get(@Req res): Promise<UserVm> {
    // extract auth user from request object
    // return auth user
}

@Get(':id') // uuid
async get(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<UserSummaryVm> {
    // return a summary user profile
}
...
```

Howvever, the `/:id` is overriding the `/me`. I have tried reorder the routes to no avail. I always get the following error:

```
[Nest] 94764   - 8/23/2018, 7:45:50 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] Could not find 
any entity of type "User" matching: "me"
EntityNotFound: Could not find any entity of type "User" matching: "me"
at new EntityNotFoundError
([PROJECT_ROOT]\src\error\EntityNotFoundError.ts:11:9)
at [PROJECT_ROOT]\src\entity-manager\EntityManager.ts:622:39
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

How do i resolve this? Any hint or pointer is appreciated.

Comment: This is still javascript at the end of the day and we don't have that "fancy" overloading-methods that other OOP languages have. Just name your methods differently (getById and get)

Answer (score 6):

By default all API-Endpoint show with this standard:

```
GET    ../user      =>  [user1, user2, user3]
GET    ../user/1    =>  user1
PUT    ../user/1    =>  user1(that updated)
DELETE ../user/1    =>  user1(that deleted)
```

### SOLUTION A

that means regular pattern must follow this order, but for new situation or case like your it can use other method like:

```
GET  ../user       =>  [user1, user2, user3] all user
GET  ../user/id/1  =>  user1
GET  ../user/me    =>  userX
```

### SOLUTION B

change the position of method in class may have effect on your response.

```
@Get(':id')
async get(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<UserSummaryVm> {
    if ( !Number.isInteger(id) ) next();
    ...
}

@Get('me')
async get(@Req res): Promise<UserVm> {
    ...
}
```

In this arranging, all request checked, if they have number in URL like *id* that to be absorbed by ***@Param('id') id: string*** execute firstly and then if there is no number in request parameter goes further.

```
 if ( !Number.isInteger(id) ) next();
```

If statement change the role and goes to next middleware if input parameter was not **INTEGER**.